# How can I group a crystal report based on multiple boolean fields?

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

My data table looks something like this (first row = column names):

> Name; Number; Group 1; Group 2; Group 3;

```
Leslie; 555-555-5555; Y; N; Y;
John; 555-555-1234; N; Y; N;
Mary; 555-555-2222; Y; Y; N;
James; 555-555-3333; N; N; Y;
Sue; 555-555-4444; Y; Y; Y;
```

I want my report to look like this:

> Group Name 1

```
  Leslie; 555-555-5555
  Mary; 555-555-2222
  Sue; 555-555-4444
```

> Group Name 2

```
  John; 555-555-1234
  Mary; 555-555-2222
  Sue;  555-555-4444
```

> Group Name 3

```
  Leslie; 555-555-5555
  James;  555-555-3333
  Sue;  555-555-4444
```

I feel like I must be overthinking this.  Can someone please advise me of the best way to group my report based on multiple boolean fields (and allow the report to repeat details as necessary)?

Thanks in advance,

Leslie Waters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to change your record source to group them the way you want.

Example:

```
SELECT 'Group 1' as GroupName, Name, Number
FROM Table
WHERE Group1 = 'Y'

UNION

SELECT 'Group 2' as GroupName, Name, Number
FROM Table
WHERE Group2 = 'Y'

UNION

SELECT 'Group 3' as GroupName, Name, Number
FROM Table
WHERE Group3 = 'Y'
```

**OR**

You could create a sub report for each group - each sub-report would select the same records except filter them to show only the particular group

Comment: This looks like a good option... I'll test it out and post back the results.  Should work, in theory.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Group on a formula.  Make the formula a concatenation of whatever fields you wish to be in the composite key.

Comment: That won't work - the OP wants single records to show up in more than one group ie. "Leslie" shows up twice